# variable scope inside try catch block

Tags: c#, exception, scope

I'm getting an error while trying to close my file in the `Finally` code block:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("c:\\j\\MyFile1.txt");

        string line = "";

        while (line != null)
        {
            line = myReader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        //myReader.Close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sorry file not found! {0}", e.Message);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have given the wrong path for the file! {0}", e.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry you typed in a wrong file name! {0}", e.Message);
    }
    finally
    { 
        myReader.Close();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: And are you going to tell us the error or shall we guess?

Comment: Error: The name 'myReader' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare your variables before the try:

```
StreamReader myReader = null;
```

etc.  Then set them in the try block.

Comment: line can stay inside the try block as its scope is within the block

Answer (score 6):

You would need to declare your `StreamReader` above the `try`.

That being said, I would recommend using the `using` statement instead of try/finally in this case, as it's designed specifically for resource cleanup.

```
using (StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("c:\\j\\MyFile1.txt"))
{
    try
    {
        string line = "";

        while (line != null)
        {
            line = myReader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sorry file not found! {0}", e.Message);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have given the wrong path for the file! {0}", e.Message);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry you typed in a wrong file name! {0}", e.Message);
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

This will guarantee that the `StreamReader` is closed, but do so in a more idomatic C# way.  `StreamReader`'s `IDisposable.Dispose` implementation will close the stream

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your `StreamReader` instance outside the `try`/`catch`/`finally` blocks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (StreamReader myReader = null)
    {
    try
    {
        myReader = new StreamReader("c:\\j\\MyFile1.txt");

        string line = "";

        while (line != null)
        {
            line = myReader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        //myReader.Close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sorry file not found! {0}", e.Message);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have given the wrong path for the file! {0}", e.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry you typed in a wrong file name! {0}", e.Message);
    }
    finally
    { 
        myReader.Close();
    }
}
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: can u plz show this by a code example because i have tried declaring it outside the try block but it isnt working

Comment: Error: The name 'myReader' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Thank you every one for helping me out there! i fixed it with ofcourse all of yours help! God bless

Answer (score 1):

just define `myReader` outside your try block and in finally block check for null before calling close

```
StreamReader myReader = null;
try
{
    myReader = new StreamReader("c:\\j\\MyFile1.txt");
    //.....
```

In Finally block

```
finally
{ 
    // Performs the operations that should be accomplished for eg closing the connections, file, database
    if(myReader != null)
        myReader.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do it like this

```
StreamReader myReader = null;
try
        {

           myReader  = new StreamReader("c:\\j\\MyFile1.txt");
            string line = "";

            while (line != null)
            {
                line = myReader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(line);


            }

            //myReader.Close();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("sorry file not found! {0}", e.Message);

        }

        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have given the wrong path for the file! {0}", e.Message);

        }



        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you typed in a wrong file name! {0}", e.Message);


        }

        finally
        { 
            // Performs the operations that should be accomplished for eg closing the connections, file, database
            if(myReader !=null)
            myReader.Close();

        }



        Console.ReadLine();


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you every one for helping me out there! i fixed it with ofcourse all of yours help! God bless!